# CSS parsing error and not understanding the components

Tags: css

I am reading a codebase and trying to replicate it part by part. However I am getting a css parsing error for the following css line:

```
#pp:not([class*="pelwqu"]) #s199 {
  background-image: url("https://bgnmypdu.helldomain.oy.ne.ro");
}
```

Additionally, I did not get the components of this line. Can you explain which part is needed for what and why? Thank you.

Comment: What is giving your the parsing error and what exactly is the error message? There is nothing wrong with the CSS you have provided except I can't see that URL. If you still have problems please provide a runnable snippet so we can test for ourselves.

Comment: ...and 'I did not get the components of this line' - there is no line in your question and by 'get' do you mean 'understand'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit is basically correct although using something like this complex is a hackish solution at best and should not be encouraged.

It's applying a background image to an element with id="s199" that is inside of an element that has id="pp" but doesn't have a class that contains the string "pelwqu".